# Python pickle crash when trying to return default value in __getattr__

Tags: python, python-2.7, pickle

I have a dictionary like class that I use to store some values as attributes.  I recently added some logic(`__getattr__`) to return None if an attribute doesn't exist.  As soon as I did this pickle crashed, and I wanted some insight into why?

Test Code:

```
import cPickle
class DictionaryLike(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.__dict__)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if(self.__dict__.has_key(key)):
            return self.__dict__[key]
        else:
            return None

    ''' This is the culprit...'''    
    def __getattr__(self, key):
        print 'Retreiving Value ' , key
        return self.__getitem__(key)

class SomeClass(object):
    def __init__(self, kwargs={}):
       self.args = DictionaryLike(**kwargs)


someClass = SomeClass()
content = cPickle.dumps(someClass,-1)
print content
```

---

Result:

```
Retreiving Value  __getnewargs__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File <<file>> line 29, in <module>
    content = cPickle.dumps(someClass,-1)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`
```

---

Did I do something stupid?  I had read a post that deepcopy() might require that I throw an exception if a key doesn't exist? If this is the case is there any easy way to achieve what I want without throwing an exception?

End result is that if some calls

```
someClass.args.i_dont_exist
```

I want it to return None.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Implementing `__getattr__` is a bit tricky, since it is called for every non-existing attribute.  In your case, the `pickle` module tests your class for the [`__getnewargs__`](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#object.__getnewargs__) special method and receives `None`, which is obviously not callable.

You might want to alter `__getattr__` to call the base implementation for magic names:

```
def __getattr__(self, key):
    if key.startswith('__') and key.endswith('__'):
        return super(DictionaryLike, self).__getattr__(key)
    return self.__getitem__(key)
```

I usually pass through all names starting with an underscore, so that I can sidestep the magic for internal symbols.

Comment: I think this might be best for my case, since _ and \_\_ will never be attribute names.

Comment: This is really clever I never thought to do it

Comment: dude you you saved me so much here

Answer (score 5):

You need to raise an `AttributeError` when an attribute is not present in your class:

```
def __getattr__(self, key):
    i = self.__getitem__(key)
    if i == None:
        raise AttributeError
    return self.__getitem__(key)
```

I am going to assume that this behavior is required.  From the python documentation for [getattr](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__), "Called when an attribute lookup has not found the attribute in the usual places (i.e. it is not an instance attribute nor is it found in the class tree for self). name is the attribute name. This method should return the (computed) attribute value or raise an AttributeError exception."

There is no way to tell pickle etc that the attribute it's looking for is not found unless you raise the exception.  For example, in your error message pickle is looking for a special callable method called `__getnewargs__`, pickle expects that if the AttributeError exception is not found the return value is callable.

I guess one potential work around you could perhaps try defining all of the special methods pickle is looking for as dummy methods?

Comment: @Nix: Oh I didn't see your last comment

Comment: It might not be possible to obtain what I want... I just wanted to get around having to check hasattr each time.

Comment: @Nix: Ferdinand posted an answer that may work by calling the parent classes default methods.

Comment: I just saw it, thanks for your help  +1 for explaining my oversight (that some people might programmaticly key of of the exception from getattr).