# How to pickle python object derived from dict

Tags: python, pickle

Here is my class that I need to pickle:

```
class sdict(dict):
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return self.get(attr, None)
    __setattr__= dict.__setitem__
    __delattr__= dict.__delitem__
    __reduce__ = dict.__reduce__
```

It seems to me that `__reduce__` should take care of pickling, but instead:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/daniyar/work/Apr24/<ipython-input-28-1cc94b920737> in <module>()
----> 1 pickle.dumps(sdict(a=1))

/usr/lib/python2.6/pickle.pyc in dumps(obj, protocol)
   1364 def dumps(obj, protocol=None):
   1365     file = StringIO()
-> 1366     Pickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
   1367     return file.getvalue()
   1368 

/usr/lib/python2.6/pickle.pyc in dump(self, obj)
    222         if self.proto >= 2:
    223             self.write(PROTO + chr(self.proto))
--> 224         self.save(obj)
    225         self.write(STOP)
    226 

/usr/lib/python2.6/pickle.pyc in save(self, obj)
    304             reduce = getattr(obj, "__reduce_ex__", None)
    305             if reduce:
--> 306                 rv = reduce(self.proto)
    307             else:
    308                 reduce = getattr(obj, "__reduce__", None)

/usr/lib/python2.6/copy_reg.pyc in _reduce_ex(self, proto)
     82             dict = None
     83     else:
---> 84         dict = getstate()
     85     if dict:
     86         return _reconstructor, args, dict

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

ERROR: An unexpected error occurred while tokenizing input
The following traceback may be corrupted or invalid
The error message is: ('EOF in multi-line statement', (171, 0))
```

Should I define `__getstate__` too? I'm totally lost with all these multiple methods that can be used for custom pickling:  `__getinitargs__`, `__getstate__`, `__reduce__`, etc...

Google only refers me to the official pickle documentation that I find very unclear. Can someone clarify that for me or point me to a good pickle tutorial?

Comment: You haven't included the entire traceback, so it's hard to know what is going wrong.  Also, are you sure you want to get this complicated?  Inheriting from builtin types is often much more complicated than you would think.  What are you building?

Comment: I want a "." access to dictionary items. It would simplify lots of things for me. Also, given how simple this class is, I am sure that there is a very simple trick that would make it pickle

Comment: Using `.` seems like an odd way to access items in a dictionary - it will only work when the keys are strings, and will cause confusion when you try to access a method of the dictionary, like `sdict.items`.  Can't the items in the dictionary just be attributes of an object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I question whether you are headed down a good path.

But, to fix the pickle problem:

```
class sdict(dict):
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        if attr.startswith('__'):
            raise AttributeError
        return self.get(attr, None)
    __setattr__= dict.__setitem__
    __delattr__= dict.__delitem__
```

Pickle is trying to get state from your object, and dict doesn't implement it.  Your `__getattr__` is being called with `"__getstate__"` to find that magic method, and returning None instead of raising `AttributeError` as it should.  If you fix your `__getattr__`, pickle works properly.

In fact, why are you returning None for missing attributes anyway?  Is that really what you want your object to do?

This is an example of the difficulty of faking builtins as you are trying to do.  There is subtle stuff going on under the covers, and you will have to be involved with it.

PS: an [identical question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6415951/python-pickle-crash-when-trying-to-return-default-value-in-getattr).

Comment: Thank you, it works! So, what's the difference between attributes defined explicitly in the class definition and those for which `__getattr__` is called? It seems that in my example I don't need `__setattr__= dict.__setitem__` with this new `__getattr__` function. Alternatively, I should be able to get rid of `raise AttributeError` if I create necessary for pickling methods explicitly. Am I correct and what should these methods be?

Comment: You don't want to provide pickling methods, you don't need them.  It's rare to need to provide `__reduce__` or `__getstate__`.  PS: don't forget to accept answers!

Comment: I'm trying to understand how it works internally: `if attr.startswith('__'): print attr; raise AttributeError` prints `__getnewargs__` and `__getstate__` while pickling. But if I explicitly define `__getnewargs__ = dict.__getnewargs__` and the same for `__getstate__` pickling doesn't work.

Comment: Is it better to put attribute error in the way this answer did, or just to define __getstate__() and have it return an Attribute Error